# how slow down jquery scrollTo to avoid animation flashing

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I am currently using the following code, but I need to slow it down even more to avoid the animation flashing. The site is published dot mobi

```
 $('#nav a, #top-nav a, #bottom-nav a').click(function(e){
    var my_offset = $(this.hash).offset().top;

    $('body').scrollTo(this.hash, {duration:'slow'});
    //$('html, body').scrollTo(this.hash, this.hash);

    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: my_offset 
}, 2000); // 2000ms  = 2s duration
```

Comment: Thanks, by the way the animation flashing only happens on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saying slow, put the value in milliseconds(1000 = 1 second).
eg.

```
$('#nav a, #top-nav a, #bottom-nav a').click(function(e){
var my_offset = $(this.hash).offset().top;

$('body').scrollTo(this.hash, {duration:'2000'});
//$('html, body').scrollTo(this.hash, this.hash);

return false;
   });
```

Comment: Note: if you chose to use jQuery animate, look into TweenMax(for example of speed and power, look to Intel's homepage) from Greensock(http://www.greensock.com/), it is much faster!

Answer (score 0):

If your browser is flashing it means that you dont have a powerful browser or your system resources are not enough. Rather use hide() and show() instead of animate. When you do hide, hide after a second or two to avoid flashing.